# What do the 'quiet' and 'all topics' checkboxes in rxgraph do?

Tags: ros, rxgraph

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The most that the [wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rxgraph) says about these is:

> **Removed in ROS 1.1**
>
> The -q and -t options were removed
> from the command-line and replaced
> with check boxes in the toolbar.

What exactly do they actually do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36536/what-do-the-%27quiet%27-and-%27all-topics%27-checkboxes-in-rxgraph-do?/) by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2264 on 2012-06-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The quiet option removes the following nodes:

```
['/diag_agg', '/runtime_logger', '/pr2_dashboard', '/rviz', 
'/rosout', '/cpu_monitor', '/monitor','/hd_monitor', '/rxloggerlevel', '/clock']
```

Usually, the graph displays Nodes as, well, nodes, and the topics that connect them as edges.

If you use the topics mode, the graphs and the topics will both be nodes.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2012-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2012-06-14**:
Thanks. Not sure why it's called "all topics" rather than "show topics as vertices" or even "boxes around topics". Since turning it on usually causes dot to come up with a totally new layout it isn't obvious what effect that option has.